# 1/0 and 1/2 binary columns are treated equally when training deep learning models?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Usually when I have columns that are binary I do not perform any transformation since it is already one-hot encoded. What happens when binary column consist of two values but are not 1/0? Would column with 1/2 have greater impact on learning?

Answer (score 0):

Some modeling libraries can/are-designed-to take care of such difference will end up in no difference. If you are referring to the features/independent-variables, then your normalization technique will take care of that difference and again, end up in no difference.

If you don't normalize and choose to use (e.g.) 100/0 instead of 1/0, then distance-based ML (e.g. K-means) will be affected, but decision tree won't be affected.

While theoretically it should not have an impact, practically it depends on how we clean our data to make sure it does not have an impact.